# How can I get the full url of the image in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, imagefield

I am not good at English. I hope you understand.

1. There can be multiple images in the diary.
2. Diary and DiaryImage are in a 1:N relationship.

this is my model

```
from django.db import models

from userSystem.models import User


class Diary(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="diary_user", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=800)
    date_created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)


class DiaryImage(models.Model):
    diary = models.ForeignKey(Diary, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='/media/diary/default_image.jpeg', upload_to='diary',
                              blank=True, null=True)
```

this is my serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from diary.models import DiaryImage, Diary


class DiaryImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DiaryImage
        fields = ['image']


class DiarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_images(self, obj):
        image = obj.diaryimage_set.all()
        return DiaryImageSerializer(instance=image, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Diary
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'content', 'date_created', 'images']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        instance = Diary.objects.create(**validated_data)
        image_set = self.context['request'].FILES
        for image_data in image_set.getlist('image'):
            DiaryImage.objects.create(diary=instance, image=image_data)
        return instance
```

this is my view

```
from diary.serializers import DiarySerializer


class DiaryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, ]
    serializer_class = DiarySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.diary_user.all()
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

urls.py

```
diary_list = DiaryViewSet.as_view({"get": "list", "post": "create"})


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('diary/', diary_list, name="diary-list"),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

When I ran this code, the image was saved successfully.
However, when loading the saved image, the full url does not appear.

Like this,

```
{
    "id": 70,
    "title": "hello!",
    "content": "hello_content",
    "date_created": "2021-03-31",
    "images": [
        {
            "image": "/media/diary/DRF_Imagefield_1_xVENDCo.png"
        },
        {
            "image": "/media/diary/django_test_IGFIyYm.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get the full url of the image?

Comment: you can return the image url like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26385269/11225821

Comment: I tried this, but the result was the same. 

class DiaryImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_image_url')

    def get_image_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url

    class Meta:
        model = DiaryImage
        fields = ['image_url']

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `FileField` and `ImageField` automatically try to use the `request` from the `context` if it is passed to the serializer to build the absolute url. You should pass the context from your `DiarySerializer` to the `DiaryImageSerializer`:

```
class DiarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_images(self, obj):
        image = obj.diaryimage_set.all()
        return DiaryImageSerializer(instance=image, many=True, context=self.context).data
    
    # Rest of code
```